# What Happens to Non-Awaited Tasks In Try/Catch Block

Tags: c#, async-await

What happens when a method returns a `Task` that is contained in a `try/catch` block? If that non-awaited `Task` throws an exception, is the exception caught/handled?

For example, if `DoSomethingAsync()` throws an exception, can I handle it in the `try/catch` block in `TryCatchMethod()`?

```
Task TryCatchMethod()
{
    try
    {
        return DoSomethingAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}

async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   await Task.Delay(10000);
   throw new System.Exception();
}
```

Comment: Not unless you `await` `DoSomethingAsync`.

Comment: That depends. If for example you have method `Task DoSomethingAsync() { throw new Exception("test")}` - this exception will be caught by your try-catch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Answer

No, the `try/catch` block in `TryCatchMethod()` will not catch an exception if one occurs in `DoSomethingAsync()` because of 2 reasons:

1. The exception will be caught in `MoveNext()`
2. `DoSomethingAsync()` is not `await`d, so the exception will never be rethrown

## Solutions

1. Await `DoSomethingAsync()` *(Prefered)*

```
async Task TryCatchMethod()
{
    try
    {
       await DoSomethingAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}
```

2. Use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

```
void TryCatchMethod()
{
    try
    {
       DoSomethingAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}
```

**Note**: `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is not recommended because it will lock the current thread.

## Explanation

To understand why the `try/catch` block doesn't catch the exception, it's important to first understand how the compiler generates IL code for an `async` method.

### Compiler-Generated Code for Async Method

[image]

(Source: [Xamarin University: *Using Async and Await*](https://university.xamarin.com/classes/track/csharp#csc350-async))

The compiler transforms an `async` method into an `IAsyncStateMachine` class which allows the .NET Runtime to "remember" what the method has accomplished.

[image]

(Source: [Xamarin University: *Using Async and Await*](https://university.xamarin.com/classes/track/csharp#csc350-async))

The `IAsyncStateMachine` interface implements `MoveNext()`, a method that executes everytime the `await` operator is used inside of the `async` method.

`MoveNext()` essentially runs your code until it reaches an `await` statement, then it `return`s while the `await`'d method executes. This is the mechanism that allows the current method to "pause", yielding its thread execution to another thread/Task.

#### Try/Catch in `MoveNext()`

Look closely at `MoveNext()`; notice that it is wrapped in a `try/catch` block.

Because the compiler creates `IAsyncStateMachine` for every `async` method and `MoveNext()` is *always* wrapped in a `try/catch`, every exception thrown inside of an `async` method is caught!

### How to Rethrow an Exception Caught By `MoveNext`

Now the question becomes, if every `async` method catches every exception thrown, How can I rethrow the exception?

There are a few ways to rethrow exceptions that are thrown in an `async` method:

1. Use the `await` keyword *(Prefered)*

   - e.g. `await DoSomethingAsync()`
2. Use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

   - e.g. `DoSomethingAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

The `await` keyword is preferred because `await` allows the `Task` to run asynchronously on a different thread, and it will not lock-up the current thread.

#### What About `.Result` or `.Wait()`?

Never, never, never, never, never use `.Result` or `.Wait()`:

1. Both `.Result` and `.Wait()` will lock-up the current thread. If the current thread is the Main Thread (also known as the UI Thread), your UI will freeze until the `Task` has completed.
   2.`.Result` or `.Wait()` rethrow your exception as a `System.AggregateException`, which makes it difficult to find the actual exception.

#### Example

**Don't Do This**

```
var longRunningTask1 = LongRunningTaskAsync();
var longRunningTask2 = LongRunningTaskAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(longRunningTask1, longRunningTask2);

var result1 = longRunningTask1.Result;
var result2 = longRunningTask2.Result;
```

**Instead, Do This**

```
var longRunningTask1 = LongRunningTaskAsync();
var longRunningTask2 = LongRunningTaskAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(longRunningTask1, longRunningTask2);

var result1 = await longRunningTask1;
var result2 = await longRunningTask2;
```

Answer (score 8):

If `DoSomethingAsync` throws an exception, the exception is caught.  If it returns a faulted task, instead of throwing, then there is no exception to catch until you try to get the task's result (by awaiting it).  Since you don't do that in your `try` block, it won't run your `catch` block.

Note that if the method is marked as `async` any exceptions thrown in the body of that method are caught and result in the method returning a faulted task, rather than the method throwing an exception.  For the method to throw an exception the method would need to return a `Task` without being marked as `async`.

Comment: The following will reach OPs catch block even when marked as async: `async Task DoSomethingAsync() {Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();}`. A bit contrieved but still.

Comment: @Evk You could also have the method go into infinite recursion, or consume more than the available memory, or do other such things that cause the environment itself to throw an exception, rather than for that method to throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown when the task is awaited. The compiler generated code when a task is awaited with the await key word cleverly unwraps the exceptions and throws them how you would expect with a reasonably sensible stack trace. It is also thrown if you access the result of the task or call wait but it's then thrown as an aggregate exception and this isn't the best practice. If you never await the task the exception eventually becomes an unoberserved  task exception and can be fatal to your program and also has a rubbish stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Exception will be thrown when you access result of task execution with `await task`, `task.Result` or `task Wait()`.

In your case, if exception is thrown inside a task within `DoSomethingAsync()`, it will not be caught by `TryCatchMethod()` but will be caught by an outer method that awaits on the task returned by `TryCatchMethod()`.

Check for more details: [Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)